# java -setting the location of manually compiled class files

Tags: java, file-io, javac, .class-file

I have created a class to manually compile my .java files into .class files. This program works successfully . But, .class files are created in the same directory as my .java files. But, I want them to be created in some custom directory. What can I do?

Below is the code I am using to compile .java files. :-

//*************************************************//

//this will compile my .java file into .class file and store it in the same location

```
public void compileFile(String pageName,String packageName) {

    String fileToCompile = packageName  + pageName +".java";

    System.out.println("String to compile :- " + fileToCompile );

    System.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\install\\Java\\jdk1.7");
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);

            if(compilationResult == 0){

                System.out.println("Compilation is successful");

            }else{

                System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
              //  this.deleteFiles(fileToCompile);

            }


    }
```

//this method tries to move (by copy and paste) my generated .class file into custom directory.
but it gives some error like  bad class file: mycustomdir\MarketWatchBean.class
 class file contains wrong class: mycustomdir.MarketWatchBean
 Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

```
public void moveFiles(String sourcePath, String destPath){

        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;

            try{

                File afile =new File(sourcePath);
                File bfile =new File(destPath);

                inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int length;
                //copy the file content in bytes 
                while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

                }

                inStream.close();
                outStream.close();

                //delete the original file
               // afile.delete();

                System.out.println("File is copied successfully!");

            }catch(IOException e){
            //  this.deleteFiles(sourcePath);
            //  this.deleteFiles(destPath);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the option `-d dest_directory` to the method `compiler.run(null,null,null,"-d destdirectory",fileToCompile);` Please ensure that the destination directory already exists.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/Tool.html#run%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String...%29),

```
int run(InputStream in,
        OutputStream out,
        OutputStream err,
        String... arguments)
```

You can pass variable number of arguments to the tool. i.e javac tool options should be passed as the arguments to this method